# Does the phrase "If you don't use it, you lose it" apply to mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I'm asking this because I ran into the following particular situation:

I took some calc courses over 2013, where I learned, amongst other things, to integrate some pretty nasty functions, and this semester, I started taking a differential equations course. To my surprise, I realized I had forgotten most I had learnt in terms of integration, and had to relearn most of the stuff on my own.

How do you guys manage to keep things you won't use for a year+ but you'll need later on in your head?

Comment: There are techniques- for examples, matrices, complex numbers and vectors are all related. So if you remember one properly, the others can be dealt with in the same way..

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no other way than practicing on a regular basis. At least that's what I see on my case and not only for Mathematics. Maybe a secondary question is what to do to in order to keep trace of what you did in the past by optimizing the effort. I would answer for Mathematics, practice the proves of the theorem and make a minimum of exercises.

Comment: Instructors observe this all the time.  Students take some time off, they forget.  In fact, even if it is just two months off between academic years, still they forget.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the word **it**. For specific details, certainly; for big ideas: It depends on how you "chunk" the information. I tried to give a concrete example in [**MESE 2226**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/2230) for a theorem such as "every closed, bounded infinite subset of real numbers contains a limit point." For this, I have a "chunked" mental model. I also gave an example for which I *don't* have a "chunked" mental model: Proving permutation groups can be partitioned into even and odd elements. (Side-note: It'd be interesting to see that proof chunked...)

Comment: Not having a very good memory, I still forget things even if only a short span of time has passed since the last time I used it. However, I compensate by trying to at least remember where to look things up (i.e. *references*) whenever I need them. But yes, practice is key, as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**(In my experience)**

Yes, you start to forget things pretty quickly if you don't practice at all.  **However,** you don't forget them permanently--ideas and concepts usually stay, and all of the material will be much easier to re-learn later if you've learned it once.

Comment: And sometimes you can re-learn the material better the second (or third) time around, since you're vaguely familiar with all the elements and how they fit together. Whereas the first time around it can be hard to learn those individual elements without a sense of the whole that they comprise.

Answer (score 9):

I left academics 20 years ago and likely have forgotten more than I retained.  And so, yes, there is something to be said for "use it or lose it.

But even then, I always tried to understand and retain the underlying principles and not just try to memorize "certain" details and results from applying those principles.

So, how does one filter "certain" details?  It is completely a judgment call.

Is it useful to memorize, for example, the indefinite integral of $x\,e^x$

$$\int x\,e^x\,dx=e^x(x-1)+C$$

or better just to understand and recall that the principle for integrating by parts and the product rule for differentiation so that

$$uv'=(uv)'-u'v\implies \int u\,dv=(uv)-\int v\,du$$

I don't find it useful to memorize the former.  But, in my humble opinion, the differentiation product rule ought to be "memorized," although I suggest that it would be even better yet to understand how to prove the rule using a basic $\delta-\epsilon$ set up.

So, the details one chooses to "memorize" are quite discretionary and one must be judicious in selecting how to separate the foundational concepts - the building blocks, so to speak - from the myriad of "results" that can be derived therefrom.

There really is no "one-shoe-fits-all" advice.  In the end, just use your best judgment and ask yourself, "Is it better to memorize a result, or recall the tools and derive the result myself?"

Comment: FWIW, I like to remember the product rule in this form $\frac{d(uv)}{(uv)}=\frac{du}{u}+\frac{dv}{v}$, since it makes it obvious how to extend it to more than two items in the product, and it also shows how the integrals are logarithmic.

Comment: @pm2ring +1 For your comment.  Of course, this post was not attempting to elucidate product rule differentiation,

Comment: I like the part "ought to be memorized ... even better yet to understand how to prove ...". Unfortunately proofs are regarded as dreadful in introductory mathematics courses (meaning intended for students of age below 16-17 years). +1 for your very nice answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks!!  I do recall, 1,000 years ago or so, when I was in high school, we did $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs.  Have things changed so much.  :-(

Comment: @Dr.MV: I think you were lucky. And also fortunate enough to live 1000 years. :):) In India I do see that introductory calculus texts avoid proofs altogether. Only when you have a proper training in "real-analysis" in an undergrad course you get to learn some decent proofs. I was however lucky to get a copy of Hardy's Pure Mathematics at age of 15 from library and never had to worry much after that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Wow!  Age 15.  I had pre-calculus at 15, but didn't start calculus until age 16.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Actually calculus started in high school at age 17, it was just a matter of great luck to get in touch with Hardy's book at a very young age and it helped me a lot with my maths education (in fact it helping me now also. Most of my answers here and posts on my blog are based on material in that book). Also the 15 in my last comment was just one month before 16 so you can count it as almost 16 years of age.

Comment: I just had a look at your blog site a short while ago and left a comment on one on the subjects.  It looks like you've poured your heart and soul into it and should be proud of the work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31345/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-dr-mv).